# Ubuntu VLC падает поток зависают xserver

Tags: ubuntu, vlc

Ubuntu desktop vlc паказывает картинку с китайской камеры.
Камера переодически перезагружается, поток падает зависают иксы намертво, остается только перезапустить их 
Строка подключения к камере
 `vlc --qt-minimal-view "rtsp://192.168.0.149:554/user=admin&password=passport&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?"`
Можно killall -9 vlc, но только когда поток упал. Как отследить, что именно он не работает?

Comment: Может проще всего по крону? Каждые 5-10-15-x минут?

Comment: Закономерности в падении не заметил может 1 час проработать, а может 3 раза 10 минут. После окнончания движения в камере, vlc перезапускается.

Comment: А если параллельно пинговать камеру и если она перестаёт отвечать на пинги, рубить vlc, ждать 30 секунд (ну типа чтобы прошивка подгрузилась) и перезапускать vlc?

Comment: Пинг на камеру идет и во время падения потока и никак не меняется

Comment: А порт 554 во время зависания остаётся открыт?

Comment: А как его проверить? nmap в цикле потом парсить?

Comment: да падает, теперь остается написать скрипт если порт упал прибивать vlc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nmap -p554 192.168.0.149 | grep -q closed || killall -9 vlc
```

Ну и чтобы оно молотило бесконечно:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "nmap -p554 192.168.0.149 | grep -q closed" ]
do
    killall -9 vlc
    vlc --qt-minimal-view "rtsp://192.168.0.149:554/user=admin&password=passport&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?" &
done
```

Вроде не напутал с синтаксисом.